# how to overcome from this "'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
File "C:/Users/kanha/PycharmProjects/automatic_game/bot.py", line 25, in <module>
    imagegrab()
  File "C:/Users/kanha/PycharmProjects/automatic_game/bot.py", line 20, in imagegrab
    image = ImageGrab(box)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

the error message im getting how to reslove it?

Comment: what is the import line?

Comment: `ImageGrab` is a module so you can't call it. Maybe you meant to call `ImageGrab.ImageGrab` or `ImageGrab.grab`, or you meant to do something different in the import line like `from ImageGrab import ImageGrab`.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageGrab` is a module so you can't call it. From a quick look at [the docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html), it looks like you meant to call

```
ImageGrab.grab
```